# ConfigurationElementCollection: filtering through lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net

I want to work with ConfigurationElementCollection items using lambda expressions. In my code I've made this to circumvent the problem:

```
IEnumerable<ProcessDataElement> processDataModelList = from ProcessDataElement pdec in processDataModel
                                                       where pdec.Name == name
                                                       select pdec;
```

In this example I'm reading a `ProcessDataElementCollection` that extends `ConfigurationElementCollection`, filter through and store the result into something I can work with. **Ideally, the output type would be another collection of the same type, that contains only the filtered stuff.**

I want to remove the unneeded complexity by adding something that resembles the `.Where()` method, so I can get something like this:

```
ProcessDataElementCollection processDataModel = processDataModel.Where(x => x.Name = "foo");
```

This would be so much easier to read and maintain, but I'm a bit lost here and don't know how to implement it in my code, so any help would be appreciated.

This is the actual code signature of Where() for System.Linq.Enumerable:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
```

Here's an example of my structure. First of all, the configuration:

```
<processDataGroup>
    <processDataSettings>
      <processDataModel>
        <processData name="test" user="root" pass="1234" prog="cmd" para="/c" path="C:\run.bat" />
        <processData name="test" user="root" pass="1234" prog="cmd" para="/c" path="C:\run2.bat" />
      </processDataModel>
    </processDataSettings>
  </processDataGroup>
```

Initially I didn't have the DataGroup element, but according to standards it seems it's a good practise to have it.

Now the class is mapped as follows:

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ProcessDataElementCollection), AddItemName = "processData")]
public class ProcessDataElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public new ProcessDataElement this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            if (IndexOf(name) < 0) return null;
            return (ProcessDataElement)BaseGet(name);
        }
    }

    public ProcessDataElement this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return (ProcessDataElement)BaseGet(index);
        }
    }

    public int IndexOf(string name)
    {
        name = name.ToLower();

        for (int index = 0; index < base.Count; index++)
        {
            if (this[index].Name.ToLower() == name)
                return index;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new ProcessDataElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((ProcessDataElement)element).Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to create a new `ProcessDataElementCollection` from the results of your Where clause? Does that object have a constructor or other method of creating an object when given an `IEnumerable<ProcessDataElement>`?

Comment: @Chris No it doesn't. I want to get a collection of items, without any type transformations if possible, where I just filter out the elements I need. I don't have to create a Collection out of an IEnumerable, just take one Collection and filter it.

Comment: If you want an output of the same type, that is `ProcessDataElementCollection` then you need that object to support it in some way, eg by doing the filtering with a method itself, or you need to do the filtering yourself using LINQ or something else and create a new `ProcessDataElementCollection`. You already have the LINQ code to do it with an `IEnumerable<ProcessDataElement>` return type. If you just want that converted to method syntax (using lambda expressions) then you have already done that (though have tried to put it in a variable of the wrong type).

Comment: P.S. Why have you quoted the method signature (that isn't the implementation) of `Where`?

Comment: @Chris The only way to do this would be writing a function that filters it and returns what I need, but I don't know how to do this sort of stuff yet, because I've never really had to do it. On the last part, it should be fixed now, thanks for pointing the mistake out.

Comment: So you want to add a method or an extension method to `ProcessDataElementCollection` to allow it to filter things? Do you have access to this class to modify it? If not what constructors do you have available to make instances of that class? You already know how to filter the data so I assume the problem comes down to how to create the `ProcessDataElementCollection` instance with that data in it (or to modify the existing one)?

Comment: @Chris That's exactly what I need! And yes, I have access to the code.

Comment: You should share some of the details of the `ProcessDataElementCollection` then. We can't tell you how to modify the class without seeing the class itself. Knowing how things are stored internally for example will be important to knowing the best way to do what you want.

Comment: @Chris I added the code examples to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for object of ProcessDataElementCollection class then use the following code

```
IEnumerable<ProcessDataElementCollection > processDataModelList = from ProcessDataElement pdec in processDataModel
                                                   where pdec.Name == name
                                                   select new ProcessDataElementCollection {initialize the member here};
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants a `IEnumerable<ProcessDataElementCollection>`, just a `ProcessDataElementCollection`...

Comment: That's not the answer I was looking for indeed. Lambda expressions are mandatory for my purpose as I stated before. I'll add some code to the first post, check the 3rd code example to see what I mean.